# SQL Server operation without asp.net page load

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, tcp

I am totally new in the asp.net and SQL server field.

My question is that,

My aspx page is in IIS web server. This webpage communicates with my field device via TCP and stores the data in the SQL Server on page load(via background c# Code). Now want I want to know is that if I do not open the webpage in the browser is it possible that I can get the data using TCP and store it into SQL Server if the page is not open in any web browser and on server only?

I will tell you a bit about my application here, the data is coming in every one second from my field device to the server and it stores it into SQL Server. And after that I am displaying the data into graph format in span of hours in the aspx page. So anyone can operate and monitor whats happening in the field remotely from any where in the world. But for storing the data I need to load the page. 
I want to record and store the data even the page is not open.(silently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into creating a WCF service instead. It will let you make requests directly without having to rely on a browser. You can configure your service over tcp

Comment: well I will tell you a bit about my application here, the data is coming in every one second from my field device to the server and it stores it into SQL Server. And after that I am displaying the data into graph format in span of hours in the aspx page. So anyone can operate and monitor whats happening in the field remotely from any where in the world. But for storing the data I need to load the page thats where I am stuck.

Comment: You can consider refreshing the page through ajax requests. Look into SignalR or similar

Comment: I thought of that, but what if the page is not open....I still want to store the data in that case.......